# FTL - How to get values of JSON object correctly

Tags: json, freemarker

I am pretty new in FTL so this may be a stupid question however I wasn't lucky to solve it.

I have a JSON object:

```
 {
    "Q1": "KOŽENÝ VOLANT",
    "Q5": "ZESÍLENÉ ZÁVĚSY KOL",
    "Q6": "AIRBAG SPOLUJEZDCE",
    "M3": "BOČNÍ OCHR - LIŠ MALÉ",
    "Q7": "SERVOŘÍZENÍ ELEKTR",
    "M4": "SP"
 }
```

And I need to access this texts on right side.
How I do it:

```
<#function getModelOptions>
    <#local results = []>
        <#list case.vehicleData.modelOptions?keys as key>
            <#local results = results+[case.vehicleData.modelOptions[key]]>
        </#list>
    <#return results>
</#function>
```

and after that something like:

```
<#assign dataVybavaVozidla = getModelOptions() >
<@input.draw2ColumnNoBorderTable nadpis="Výbava vozidla" data=dataVybavaVozidla />
```

This works for me on 90% cases, but in some it just throw me an error:

```
> ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
>         - Failed at: #local results = results + [case.vehi...  [in template "path/to/template.ftl" in function "getModelOptions" at line
> 1501, column 25]
>         - Reached through: #assign dataVybavaVozidla = getModelO...  [in template "path/to/template.ftl" at line 674, column 17]
> ----
```

I try to compare data in both cases, when it works and when it doesn't work correctly. Both look same. I also try to just

```
<#list case.vehicleData.modelOptions?keys as key>
    <tr>${key}</tr>
</#list>
```

which display me my keys correctly :(

EDIT:
Atm it looks like (I can't confirm) is that it can be some special character like `&` and  `null` in text.

Comment: Can't you just use `case.vehicleData.modelOptions?values`?

Comment: The top of the quoted error messages is missing. Also, you could print the key when the error occurs using `<#attempt>...<#recover>...</#attempt>`, so you don't have to guess. Anyway, FreeMarker doesn't care about `&` in the key. It's certainly a `null` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If your data can contain null values, then add a null-check:

```
<#if case.vehicleData.modelOptions[key]??>
    <#local results = results+[case.vehicleData.modelOptions[key]]>
</#if>
```

Comment: hi rostanek, you are right, it create array of JSON object, however each of this have one specific value. Your result will return just a key which I already have

Comment: Hi, you wrote that you need "texts on left site", so I assumed that you want the keys. If your data can contain null value, then you should add some null-check, because FreeMarker fails when it encounters null.